# how can I resolve " Cannot read property 'getContext' of null "

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, rgraph

I'am facing issue while calling `rgraph` canvas in asp `mvc`. Here is my code and I add all required links of `rgraphs`. And `jquery` file too. And facing an error " Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property getContext` of null "

```
var key = RGraph.HTML.Key('containerPie', {
  colors: ['blue', 'green'],
  labels: response.labels,
  tableCss: {
    //position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    right: '-80px',
    transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
  }
});

new RGraph.Pie({
  id: 'cvsPie',
  data: response.res,
  options: {
    strokestyle: '#e8e8e8',
    variant: 'pie3d',
    linewidth: 2,
    gutterLeft: 5,
    shadowOffsetx: 0,
    shadowOffsety: 7,
    shadowColor: '#ddd',
    shadowBlur: 15,
    radius: 40,
    tooltips: response.res,
    colors: ['blue', 'green']
  }
}).draw();
```

And here is my div code:

```
<canvas id="cvsPie" width="450" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: And here is my div code  <canvas id="cvsPie" width="450" height="300"></canvas>

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that the canvas object is null, so there's no getContext() method. Usually this is down to using the wrong ID - which by the looks of it you haven't - or running the code before the canvas exists.

This second one could be your issue - where the code is above the canvas tag in the page and you're not not using the DOMContentLoaded event or window.onload event.

So try moving the  code that creates the chart just after the canvas tag or put your code inside the onload event like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
</script>
```